# Hot water sound through pipes behind shower wall

Tags: plumbing, water, leak

There are hot water sounds like water running through pipes behind shower wall. Checked meter, it shows water running. No apparent leaks at all points - faucets, valves, etc. Turned off hot water at water heater, sounds stops. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's obvious water is running in some manner.  More info would be helpful - is this a single family dwelling, where in the country do you live, what's underneath that spot you're hearing water running?

Comment: Single family house, San Diego area known for hard water. Shower suddenly had excessive hot water, faulty faucet cartridge changed out with new cartridge, water faucet works great now. But at the same time as the faucet cartridge issue the hot water running began and continues even with the new cartridge. Cut basketball-sized hole in wall and cannot find/detect leaks. However when the hot water is on (the hot water heater) the water meter is running. Is hiring a pro to use all his detection tools to source out "leaks" a good idea?

Comment: BTW - I decided to run the dishwasher turning on the water heater and I do not hear the running water in the shower wall. Could be that dishwasher has lowered/diverted water pressure away from shower wall? I'll check if it remains after the dishwashing is done.

Comment: what's a hot water sound?

Comment: If you cut the hole near the shower mixer, start touching the cold pipe to see if it gets hot when the water noise is happening. My gut is that the cartridge is allowing hot back into the cold pipe.

Comment: The temperature regulator in the cartridge was part of the noise problem; so the bad cartridge was replaced - no more hissing sound! However, the sound of hot water running in the pipes is still present. Running the dishwasher that is over 40 ft away stopped the sound of hot water running in the pipes. After the dishwasher finished the running water sound slowly returned in the wall. Before tearing walls open where the running water sound is coming from could the sound actually be coming from somewhere else? My fear, can a leak under the slab be heard in pipes 3ft - 4ft above the ground?

Comment: Yes, a leak under the slab could translate to a rushing sound, but that’s not the obvious thing, given that you’ve just touched the shower mixer. Do any of the nearby cold water supplies run warm?

Comment: Cold water does not run warm and no warmth through floor. When hot water off at water heater, sound of running water in wall ceases and the water meter shows no water is flowing through pipes into the house. When water heater turned back on the water meter shows water is being used in the house ene with all faucets off.. Running water sound is back in shower wall but I don't see any indication that water is leaking like wet drywall or water running down pipes. Could water be leaking under slab even though the sound of running water is in the pipe above ground?